# R calculate percentile using Stata definition

Tags: r, stata, definition, percentile

I did two different analyses. One with R and another with Stata, based on percentile calculation. However I have a mismatch between the two results due to a different percentile method calculation between R and Stata. Do you know if I can use the Stata's percentile definition in R?

Comment: Please provide some data to show the differences. Also include the command(s) you used in Stata and the functions you used in R.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have data sample and Stata's command to provide you. On R I'm using  the (u)ecdf(u)(u)) function. But Stata and R give differents results. And I would like to know if we can choose one specific method on R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R has at least 9 definitions of quantiles and percentiles  <strike>are just `quantile(.) * 100`</strike>. [This link](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-06/msg00155.html) suggests that the corresponding quantile-`type` would be `type=4`.  I was unable to find a percentile or quantile function documented in the Base Stata Manual, but I would welcome correction if that is in error.

Nick Cox is right. The quantile (the value in the data domain) at probability of 0.25 is the 25th percentile. The question appears unclear on both sides of the R-Stata divide because the original efforts in R were being done with the `ecdf` function in an unspecified manner. Fortunately the poster was satisfied by being pointed toward the R quantile function.

After looking at the [Version 13 Stata Manual section on centile](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rcentile.pdf), I'm not sure it matches up with any of the R quantile methods although it would appear to match the type=4 method for percentiles away from the "extremes":

> By default, centile estimates Cq for the variables in varlist and for
>   the values of q given in centile(numlist). It makes no assumptions about the distribution of X, and, if necessary, uses linear interpolation between neighboring sample values. Extreme centiles (for example, the 99th centile in samples smaller than 100) are fixed at the minimum or maximum sample
>   value

Comment: You don't mean quite what you say in so far as percentiles are **not**  the results of the `quantile()` function, multiplied by 100; rather the names or labels of percentiles correspond to those of quantiles in the way that percents correspond to proportions or fractions. `quantile()` shows such percentile labels any way, by default  0%   25%   50%   75%  100%. Otherwise put the 0.25 quantile is precisely the same value as the 25% percentile, and so forth.

Comment: Stata has several commands (not functions) for calculating quantiles or percentiles, e.g `summarize`, `centile`, etc. But until the OP shows precisely what was used in either language, it seems pointless to throw more time at the thread.